# Quantifying Uncertainty in Regression Models

Tags: r, regression, bayesian, estimation

I have the following question about quantifying uncertainty in regression models. As an example, I took a publicly available data set on heights and weights (https://gist.github.com/nstokoe/7d4717e96c21b8ad04ec91f361b000cb#file-weight-height-csv) and fit a linear regression model to this data (predicting height using weight) with the R programming language.

```
#load libraries

    library(ggplot2)
    library(dplyr)
    library(broom)
    library(ggpubr)

#load data
    my_data = read.csv("height_weight_data.csv")
    
     head(h)
    
      Gender   Height   Weight
    1   Male 73.84702 241.8936
    2   Male 68.78190 162.3105
    3   Male 74.11011 212.7409
    4   Male 71.73098 220.0425
    5   Male 69.88180 206.3498
    6   Male 67.25302 152.2122

#fit regression model
    > linear_model <- lm(Height ~ Weight, data = my_data)
    
#view model
    > summary(linear_model)
    
    Call:
    lm(formula = Height ~ Weight, data = my_data)
    
    Residuals:
        Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
    -5.8142 -0.9907  0.0263  0.9918  5.5950 
    
    Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
    (Intercept) 4.848e+01  7.507e-02   645.8   <2e-16 ***
    Weight      1.108e-01  4.561e-04   243.0   <2e-16 ***
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
    
    Residual standard error: 1.464 on 9998 degrees of freedom
    Multiple R-squared:  0.8552,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8552 
    F-statistic: 5.904e+04 on 1 and 9998 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

#plot results

height_graph<-ggplot(my_data, aes(x=Weight, y=Height))+
    geom_point()

height_graph + geom_smooth(method="lm", col="black")
```

[image]

As expected, a plot of data along with the regression model indicates that height and weight have a linear relationship - the taller someone is, the more they are expected to weigh.

We can see the regression model over here:

Height = 4.848e+01 +  1.108e-01 * Weight

**My Question:** Although completely illogical, there is technically nothing stopping this regression model from predicting the (non-sensical) height of a person with negative weight, or the height of a person with an extreme weight. For example:

- Height = 4.848e+01 +  (1.108e-01 * - 300 lbs) = 15.24 inches
- Height = 4.848e+01 +  (1.108e-01 * 6720 lbs) = 793.056 inches

Is there where the advantages of Bayesian Models comes into play? Assuming a similar Bayesian Linear Regression model was made that had "logical and realistic" priors on the model parameters - in the case where the user would try to predict the height of a "non-sensical" weight, could the Bayesian Model provide a "Red Flag"/sanity check by showing that the uncertainty on the height estimate of a person weighing 7800 lbs is very high, thereby cautioning the user to trust this estimate and review the source of this new data point?

Thanks!

Comment: The common approach to this issue are generalized linear models (GLMs) with an appropriate link function. It's typically not necessary for the `height ~ weight` relationship because values of both are so far from zero that negative values being predicted doesn't happen.

Comment: @ Ronald: Thank you for your reply! If you have time, perhaps you could provide more information about this? Thanks!

Comment: Start with reading [the Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model#Overview) then maybe study `help("glm")`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply - I have looked at these links already, they are useful, but I am not sure if they directly address the question I am asking.

Comment: If you have a response variable that can't be negative, you need to build a model that won't predict negative values. From this it follows that your relationship can't be linear in the predictors (on the response scale). You could use a transformation of your response variable (which has consequences regarding the uncertainty distribution) or you could use a GLM. I'm not sure what else I can tell you without giving a full lecture. Even with Bayesian modelling you first ensure that your model reflects fundamental properties of your data.

Comment: To check for extreme covariate patterns, one can compute the leverage of the data point and test it against its average value.

Comment: FWIW, this is obviously a fake dataset.  BTW, why don't you actually compute a prediction interval for the height of someone who weights 7800 pounds?  You might be surprised at the answer.  Hint: it tells you the model doesn't work at such weights.